# RDS Postgres Free Storage Space is fluctuating from 200GB to 0 hourly

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

As you can see, of the 500GB, we are using ~300GB and thus there is about 200GB that should be free. However, since updating from Postgres 9.4 to 9.5, we are seeing this crazy fluctuation in free storage. It is using the default parameter group as well.

Is there any way to bring it back to stable? It seems to be causing some queries to fail, too.

```
Engine version: 9.5.21
Instance class: db.t2.large
CPU: 2
RAM: 8 GB
Storage: 500 GiB
```

[image]

Some more stats:
[image]

Comment: Did you run vacuum analyze after the upgrade?  Spilling merge sorts to disk because of bad statistics could explain this.

Comment: I'm running `vacuum` now. Is `analyze` essential? It's been running for a while now, would hate to stop it.

Comment: As I understand it, the table statistics are not carried forward during upgrades, but I am by no means expert on this.  https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/12/07/postgres-statistics-and-pain-of-analyze